# In which Macbook Xcode run smoothly?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, xcode

My primary goal to purchase new Macbook is to develop iPhone, iPad and Mac applications.

I want to know in which Macbook xcode will run very smoothly ?

I have two selection option **Macbook air** and **Macbook pro**

Please help me to choose any one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most development work is typing and waiting for compilation to complete. This is possible on any modern Mac.

Both the MacBook Air and MacBook Pro will run Xcode. Developing software can stress *any* Mac, including highly specified Mac Pros.

It is unlikely anyone can clearly and definitely answer your question. All answers, including mine will be based on opinion and personal experience.